# Format Number without Decimal in Power Automate

Tags: format, numbers, decimal, power-automate

In my SharePoint list, I have a DiscountsInPercentage column has a value of 60.00% then after formatting it should return the value as 60% in Power Automate(HTML Table).

I have tried using the below expression to format the Number without decimals for the DiscountsInPercentage column,

**formatNumber(item()?['DiscountsInPercentage'],'F0')**

Thanks,
@rose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typically use the same formatting options as those available in Excel.

My suggestion, use `0%` as your formatting pattern ...

```
formatNumber(item()?['DiscountsInPercentage'],'0%')
```